# How to shrink padding/ margin top and bottom of TextInputLayout error text?

Tags: android, android-appcompat

It results in the TextInputLayout taking too much space vertically.
It's crazy that half of the TextInputLayout height is just for the error text (below the horizontal line in of `EditText`). The font size of the error text is only 11dp. Ideally, I'd like reduce the space on top and bottom of the error text to something very minimal like 2dp

I've tried everything but I've only managed to reduced the height of the TextInputLayout to 70dp.

Is there anything else that I can do?

[image]

layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/height_textinputlayout"
    android:padding="0dp"
    app:errorTextAppearance="@style/ErrorText">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/height_edittext"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="22dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="22dp"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

error style:

```
<style name="ErrorText" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:layout_margin">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/holo_red_dark</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/font_size_form_field_error</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">top</item>
        <item name="fontPath">fonts/Avalon-Book.ttf</item>
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/holo_orange_dark</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: @eric you mean your `First name` `TextInputLayout` is take too much space at bottom ?

Comment: Can you paste full snippest code of your layout. ?

Comment: @MikeM. shrink it vertically :)

Comment: @Ironman, both of them (as seen is the screenshot, they are talking the same amount of space vertically, below the horizontal line in `EditText` too much space is wasted)

Comment: @eric Try to set `setErrorEnabled(false)` to `TextInputLayout`it will hide the space.

Comment: I don't want to hide them @Ironman

Comment: @eric There is one option you can create your own class which `TextInputLayout` and make it customize as your need.

Comment: Yes, it's already in my plan @Ironman, just find it hard to believe `TextInputLayout` is does not allow me to achieve this out of the box. I thought I missed out something obvious

Comment: @eric Change your `EditText` with this `android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText`.

Comment: I'm having the same issue... Did you find a solution?

Comment: @ericn did u got solution?

Comment: @DixitPatel no solution, I gave up even though you can create a custom view class to achieve this

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45944796/1803879) is a self-authored hack to remove the bottom padding.

Answer (score 1):

While this does not solve your problem entirely it will help. I too was looking for an answer to this but not finding any solution my hacky way involves enabling and disabling the error on the TextInputLayout. It helps in some way.

```
fun clearError(til:TextInputLayout,text:Editable?,lengthCheck:Int? = null){
        if(text != null && text.isNotEmpty()){
            if(lengthCheck == null) {
                til.error = null
                til.isErrorEnabled = false
            } else if(text.length >= lengthCheck) {
                til.error = null
                til.isErrorEnabled = false
            }
        }
    }

    fun setErrorTil(til:TextInputLayout,error:String){
        if(!til.isErrorEnabled) til.isErrorEnabled = true
        til.error = error
    }
```

You can use these two functions to set the error and clear it when needed using a text watcher. Not ideal and does not answer your question but it is for passers by for whom this may help solving their use case.

textwatcher code incase you need it

```
email.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
            clearError(enameTip,s)}
        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}
        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {}
    })
```

In place of email use your edittext. Hope it helps someone. 
Also all examples are in kotlin.