# How to change TextInputLayout error container height?

Tags: android

TextInputLayout error container has large height. I want to reduce it's height. How can I do that? 
[image: change this height]

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInput"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/md_red_100"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        app:errorEnabled="true"
        android:padding="0dp"
        app:hintEnabled="false">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edittext"
            style="@style/purpleNormalEdit"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="50dp"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

thanks

Comment: Share you xml file

Comment: Similar Question but no answer to it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40756040/how-to-shrink-padding-margin-top-and-bottom-of-textinputlayout-error-text

Comment: try using      `android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"`   for Birthday field

Comment: so the height of the error textview is 10 dp?

Answer (score 3):

If your concern is to not lower the Views below when you set error to a view, try adding

```
app:helperText=" "
```

to your TextInputLayout, as the error occupies the same helper text space, you wont have any weird height issue.

Answer (score 2):

I hate hacks, but I haven't found a *solid* way of changing the error text height within a `TextInputLayout`. Therefore, I propose a *squishy* solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-10dp"
            app:errorEnabled="true">

            <com.panera.bread.common.views.PaneraEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Generic Hint"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:maxLines="1" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

I get desired height for my `TextInputLayout` by slapping it into a `LinearLayout` with the height pinned. My `TextInputLayout` wraps it's content for height and obscures the heavy padding of the error by setting a negative bottom margin.

Comment: I hate hacks too, but you gotta do something to make it work.  Thanks.

Comment: I tried this but it is not for my particular usecase. If anyone needs a different solution, mine simple enables and disables the error on the textinputlayout. A bit crude but is is useful for me. Thought I'd put it here if incase it can be useful for others. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40756040/how-to-shrink-padding-margin-top-and-bottom-of-textinputlayout-error-text/53969503#53969503